# Is it possible to load sitecore themes before loading server side scripts?

Tags: sxa

In my application `server side` scripts are loading before loading scripts from Sitecore `themes`. Is there any possibility to load Sitecore `themes` first.
I want to order the scripts of server end and Sitecore end.

Comment: Show me the code which is adding your server side scripts. How are you doing this? Why do you need such scripts?